# Can I customize the OSX screen saver to show the Day of the Week?

Tags: macos, screensaver

I would like to have a screen saver display (hopefully) a large text of today's day ... the message option on the screen saver seems to only allow fixed text with no meta tag support.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with any of Apple's screen savers that ship with OS X.

My favorite screen saver is the [Marine Aquarium](http://www.serenescreen.com/product/maquarium3x/index.php) ($20) screen saver which has a customizable crystal that can display the time (analog or digital), date, or a calendar.

If you Google "os x screen saver with date" you'll come up with many free or inexpensive alternatives. My favorite among these is the [Pong Saver](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/), but that doesn't provide the date.